# How can I start game developing in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I would like others to explain game developing to me. I have little idea to develop a 3d and 2d game in android. But I wonder if I start to develop game in android studio. Maybe whether it fail or success. 
Actually In the first time I thought develop game in android eclipse but when I got in the [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html) webpage. I saw this text;

> Important: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse is ending, per our announcement. You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrating to Android Studio.*

So, I have to start game developing with Android Studio. Basically I know core java but I have never develop a game to android. I think there is no differentiate between java and android.

1. Do you have any suggestion for me?
2. If I used to develop a game in java eclipse(which is not writing on
   android).Then when the developing game is over. Can I convert my
   java game to android ?
3. Is it possible to integrate 3d modelling(using 3ds max) in android game (using libgdx framework) ?

Comment: "*Should I start game developing by Android Studio?*" I guess you have already answered your question by quoting following from Android *Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse is ending, per our announcement. You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible.*

Comment: You plan is foredoomed to fail. You'd rather start with the very basics, creating very simple apps, learning the concept of Android and so on. You find a lot of examples on the Android developers guide.

Comment: I think I able to develop game in eclipse java. And I tried some basic game. So If I write heavy codes in eclipse java then can it be convey in android ?

Comment: You can not covert a java game to an android game, even though both are almost the same in coding. But each platform has its own language, thus you need to create games in Android Studio. If you plan to create large games, you should work on using Unity as your IDE. But you need to learn the basics of android first as Bevor said. It will help you along creating games for android.

Comment: large game means such as subway game. Unity is following c and c++ language but I cannot able develop any thing in c or c++ language

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Android development IDEs

There are a lot of IDEs for Android development. The *Android Development Tools(ADT)* Eclipse plugin is one of them.

However, Google announced that they are going to stop supporting the ADT plugin after the release of *Android Studio*. It's a better idea to use Android Studio.

You can also use alternative Android IDEs, or you can check out this [list of Android development IDEs](https://tekeye.uk/android/list-of-android-app-development-ides).

## Android Game Development

Game development is another huge branch of the Android software industry. *Canvas* drawing is the most primary method for 2D games but has poor performance.

If you need 3D, [*OpenGL ES*](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/) is a good example. According to performance issues and low development efficiency of those methods, 99.99% of game developers are using game engines to develop games.

Game engines use different programming languages such as `C++`, `C`, `Java`, `C#`, `Lua`, etc. You should select a game engine depending on your requirements of the game. There are major differences between game engines. See the following list of popular game engines:

- [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) => UnityScript, C#, Mono, Boo => 2D/3D
- [Unreal Engine 4](https://www.unrealengine.com/) => UnrealScript => 2D/3D
- [Andengine](http://www.andengine.org/) => Java => 2D
- [libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) => Java => 2D/3D
- [jMonkey](https://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) => Java => 3D
- [CryEngine](https://www.cryengine.com/) => Lua => 3D
- [Havok Vision Engine](https://www.havok.com/) =>
- <del>Project Anarchy => C++ => 3D</del> *Shut down since 2016: See [Kotaku's blog post](https://www.kotaku.com/2016/02/havok-shuts-down-its-game-engine-project-anarchy/) for more info*
- [BigWorld](http://bigworldtech.com/) => Python => 3D
- [App Game Kit](https://www.appgamekit.com/) => C++ => 2D
- [ShiVa](https://www.shiva-engine.com/) => Lua => 3D
- [HeroEngine](http://www.heroengine.com/) = > HeroScript  => 3D
- [Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/product/) => Lua => 2D

### Before you begin

You should be comfortable with programming techniques, game development,  Android development basics, and graphics. Follow some examples such as creating a snake game to grow your skills.

Read the [Beginning Android Games](ftp://ftp.heanet.ie/disk1/sourceforge/p/ph/photoshop/Beginning%20Android%20Games.pdf) book step by step to improve your skills.

Comment: did you download the ebook?

Comment: yes I had. Thank you so much for your idea. Your idea going to b effective on my development way. One more question: the modelling of character in the 3ds max can be integrated in android game ?

Comment: Could you link an updated copy of the "Beginning Android Games" book? The FTP link is broken. (I'm currently editing your answer.)